# HTML CSS Image darken grid (plugin maybe)

Tags: html, css, web, frontend

On the website below there is a full background image, and on top of that image there is that grid/net that darkens that image, what is that, where do i find it, how do i create it? (ive searched the source code, couldn't find it, help me out)

http://www.art3d.ru/

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend a technique or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a simple gradient overlay ?

```css
html {
  min-height:100%;
  background:
    linear-gradient(to left,transparent 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 50%),
    linear-gradient(to bottom,transparent 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0.3)50%),url(http://lorempixel.com/640/480);
  background-size:2px 4px, 4px 2px, cover;
}
html:hover {/* demo purpose */
  background-size: 0% 0%,0% 0%, cover;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

With the  `opacity` attribute you can darken an image. You can implement it like this:

```
body {
    background-image: url('path');
}

div {
    opacity: 0.2;
}
```

I have set a `body` background image, and when you give the `div` opactiy, it should darken the image. It can be very useful sometimes.

I hope I answered your question.